# Is there a way to force a tooltip to show in a specific place for an imput element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm working on a list of filters and due to size restraints, I want to have text input elements for each column. Each input's value will be the name of the column initially, but will be wiped out when the user clicks it. I want a way to display a tooltip above the input with the name of the column, whenever the input is being focused (so the user can see what he's doing without having to cancel his action and start again).

Comment: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Tooltip i havent used it but it might give you some ideas.

Comment: if you don't like the default behaviour then use a custom one, [like these](http://slodive.com/web-development/best-jquery-tooltip-plugins/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do this via applying CSS on Tool tip

```
.tooltip {
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #000000;
  color: #000000; outline: none;
  cursor: help; text-decoration: none;
  position: relative;
}
.tooltip div {
margin-left:50px;
margin-top:50px;
margin-right:80px;
margin-bottom:300px;
  position: absolute;
}
```